# Mysql update a table

Tags: php, mysql

How can I update a table and create column with the id numbers for each entry in that ID column?

The table currently looks like:

```
    city    
-------------
  New York
  Los Angeles
  London
  Belgrade
```

I need the column in this table that would have the ID number of each city which would be ordered by column city ASC.

Something like:

```
 id   |   city
----------------
  1   | Belgrade
  2   | London
  3   | Los Angeles
  4   | New York
```

Can I do this using mysql query or I need to do that using PHP and Mysql?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
ADD column_name column-definition;
```

so in your case its

```
 ALTER TABLE cities
 ADD id int auto-increment;
```

Comment: I am not sure this will create an ID column that would be ordered by the city column values...

Answer (score 0):

You'd be wanting to retrospectively add an identity column with auto-increment enabled to this table.

The query would look something like this:

```
ALTER TABLE city ADD id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT KEY
```

However I'm not sure if that's going to go back and fill in all the Id's for you, you might need to write a proc or another simple query to fill them in, but this will give you the column with the functionality you want going forward.

Comment: It WILL fill in the existing rows, but not necessarily according to alphabetical order of the city column.

Answer (score 0):

In case the table isn't sorted by city name at the moment, the easiest way is to create a new table, then drop the old one and rename.

```
CREATE TABLE new (
id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
city VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO new (city)
SELECT city FROM old_table ORDER BY city;

DROP TABLE old_table;
RENAME TABLE new TO old_table;
```